# ImportError: cannot import name 'CompositionView' from 'sanic.views' when I tried to install Rasa3 in python version 3.8

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

**I am facing below issue when I tried to install Rasa3 in python version 3.8**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mayurpardeshi/test/bin/rasa", line 5, in <module>
    from rasa.__main__ import main
  File "/home/mayurpardeshi/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/__main__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from rasa.cli import (
  File "/home/mayurpardeshi/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/cli/export.py", line 9, in <module>
    import rasa.core.utils
  File "/home/mayurpardeshi/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/core/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from sanic.views import CompositionView
ImportError: cannot import name 'CompositionView' from 'sanic.views' (/home/mayurpardeshi/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sanic/views.py)
```

Do anyone has solved this issue?

Comment: Composition View was deprecated since v21.6 and removed in v21.12 https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/release-notes/v21.6.html#deprecation-of-compositionview

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not getting an issue while executing any code. I am getting an issue while installation

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by a recent Sanic upgrade. It's described in more detail in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/10585).

The short-term solution is to manually install the old version of Sanic. This should suffice:

```
pip install sanic==21.9.3
```